Get list of nugets used in develop branches in multyple projects in bitbucket
We have Atlassian Bitbucket and store there too many of projects. Most of projects are compiled to nuget, which are stored in Nexus. Often we experience oversize of nugets in Nexus and we have to clean Nexus manually.
There is need in automation: need tool that will check 'develop' branch in multyple (predefined list of) projects, parse csproj files to referred versions of used nuget and result list of it.
So after analysis we could be shure that livraries that we want to delete are not in use by any project.
May be tool with this functions already exists?
We tried manual removing and expected it will be safe, but some of projects referenced to old libraries and needed exactly old versions.

So, main way is to make service which will be authenticating to bitbucket, then it will have list of repos in config and it will parse csproj files, extracted from recursive folders passing.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
